Production Technology castin
The down-sprue is 6.0 in long. Its cross-sectional area at the top=0.8 in2 and at the base = 0.6 in2. The cross-
sectional area of the runner leading from the sprue also = 0.6 in2, and it is 8.0 in long before leading into the
mold cavity, whose volume = 65 in3. The volume of the riser located along the runner near the mold cavity =
25 in3. It takes a total of 3.0 sec to fill the entire mold (including cavity, riser, runner, and sprue). This is more
than the theoretical time required, indicating a loss of velocity due to friction in the sprue and runner.
Find: (a) the theoretical velocity and flow rate at the base of the down-sprue; (b) the total volume of the mold.

Appears to be a homework or similar test question

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
